# Can someone help me with the deleting data in firebase firestore using react ? it is a Todo list and i don't know what i am missing in the code

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Component where my delete button is. i am trying to get to the collection in firestore an delete the post using its id. but nothing shows up. i don't know what i am missing. even if i think the syntax makes sense

```
function TodoList({id, title, icon}) {

const deleteTodo = ()=>{
db.collection('Todo').doc(id).delete()
}

return (
 <div className="todoList" >
    <h4 className="title">{title}</h4>
        <div className="icons">
            {icon && <DeleteIcon className="icon"  onClick={deleteTodo} />}
            {icon ?  <CheckIcon className="icon1"/> : ""}
        </div>
  </div>
 )
}
```

piece of code where i save the data in database. using db.collection firebase:

```
function TodoInput() {

const [todos, setTodos] = useState("");
const [saved, setSaved] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  db.collection('Todo').orderBy('timestamp', 'desc').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    setSaved(snapshot.docs.map(doc =>({
      id: doc.id,
      data: doc.data(),
    })))
  })
}, [])

const handleSubmit = (e)=>{
e.preventDefault();

if(!todos){

 }else{
  db.collection('Todo').add({
    title: todos,
    timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
  })
 }

setTodos('');}

return (
 <div className="todoInput" >
    <form >
        <input required type="text" placeholder="What to do ?" value={todos} 
 onChange={(e)=>setTodos(e.target.value)} />
        <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit} >ADD TODO</button>
    </form>
    
    <div className="todoListWrapper">
      <div className="todoListItem" >
        {saved.map(({id, data:{title}})=>(
            <TodoList className="todoList1" key={id} title={title} icon />
        ))}            
      </div>
    </div>    
 </div>
 )
}
```

Comment: Does any error show up in the console? If not, try adding some callbacks in case of success of error, like shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#web-version-8

Comment: It shows no error. it says "file was delete sucessfully" but nothing happened in the db. the file is still there. even on the real time listener nothing changed

Comment: Can you add a print of the firestore panel too? Showing the data that you have there